# проблема с сеткой grid. мешает верхняя часть сетки

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста :-), как сделать так, чтоб верхний длинный блок исчез? Уже промучался с блоками и никак не выходит его убрать. Как пытаюсь его убрать - сразу вся сетка слетает. Увы в сетках пока токо начинающий...((

Сейчас сетка такая:

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 300px); /*размер ячеек*/
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4,180px);/*высота ячеек*/
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: end;
}

.box {    display:block;overflow: hidden;

  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border:1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 150%;
}



.item2 {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
}

.item3 {
  grid-column: 1 / 5;
}









.effect-7 {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.effect-7 .effect-img {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 0;
}

.effect-7 .effect-img img {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transform: scale(1.2);
    left: -15px;
    transition: .5s;
}

.effect-7:hover .effect-img img {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    left: 0;
}

.effect-7 .effect-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    transition: .5s;
}

.effect-7 .effect-text h2 {
    position: relative;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.effect-7 .effect-text h2::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #ffffff;
    transition: .5s;
}

.effect-7 .effect-text p {
    position: relative;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    left: calc(-100% - 30px);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s;
}

.effect-7 .effect-text:hover h2::after {
    width: 100%;
}

.effect-7 .effect-text:hover p {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">    


      <div class="box item2">
    <div class="effect-7">
<div class="effect-img">
    <img height="240px" src="ijijimgdf/sad/bat.jpg" alt="Team Image">
</div>
<div class="effect-text">
    <h2>This is heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed purus consectetur, interdum felis in, auctor ligula.</p>
</div>
</div>

</div> 
    <div class="box item3"> <div class="effect-7">
<div class="effect-img">
    <img height="240px" src="https://static.onecms.io/wp-content/uploads/sites/20/2020/09/11/nature.jpg" alt="Team Image">
</div>
<div class="effect-text">
    <h2>This is heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed purus consectetur, interdum felis in, auctor ligula.</p>
</div>
</div></div>
    <div class="box item4"><div class="effect-7">
<div class="effect-img">
    <img height="240px" src="ijijimgdf/menu/old.png" alt="Team Image">
</div>
<div class="effect-text">
    <h2>This is heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed purus consectetur, interdum felis in, auctor ligula.</p>
</div>
</div></div>
    <div class="box item5"> <div class="effect-7">
<div class="effect-img">
    <img height="240px" src="ijijfiles/swfcas/fung.jpg" alt="Team Image">
</div>
<div class="effect-text">
    <h2>This is heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed purus consectetur, interdum felis in, auctor ligula.</p>
</div>
</div></div>
  
     <div class="box item6"><div class="effect-7">
<div class="effect-img">
    <img height="240px" src="ijijimgdf/story/med1.jpg" alt="Team Image">
</div>
<div class="effect-text">
    <h2>This is heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed purus consectetur, interdum felis in, auctor ligula.</p>
</div>
</div></div>
    <div class="box item7"><div class="effect-7">
<div class="effect-img">
    <img height="240px" src="ontent/uploads/2014/11/PROD-Adolf-Hitler-whrend-einer-Rede.jpg" alt="Team Image">
</div>
<div class="effect-text">
    <h2>This is heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed purus consectetur, interdum felis in, auctor ligula.</p>
</div>
</div></div>

    <div class="box item8"><div class="effect-7">
<div class="effect-img">
    <img height="240px" src="https://static.onecms.io/wp-content/uploads/sites/20/2020/09/11/nature.jpg" alt="Team Image">
</div>
<div class="effect-text">
    <h2>This is heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed purus consectetur, interdum felis in, auctor ligula.</p>
</div>
</div></div>    <div class="box item9"><div class="effect-7">
<div class="effect-img">
    <img height="240px" src="ontent/uploads/2014/11/PROD-Adolf-Hitler-whrend-einer-Rede.jpg" alt="Team Image">
</div>
<div class="effect-text">
    <h2>This is heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed purus consectetur, interdum felis in, auctor ligula.</p>
</div>
</div></div>


    <div class="box item10"><div class="effect-7">
<div class="effect-img">
    <img height="240px" src="ontent/uploads/2014/11/PROD-Adolf-Hitler-whrend-einer-Rede.jpg" alt="Team Image">
</div>
<div class="effect-text">
    <h2>This is heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed purus consectetur, interdum felis in, auctor ligula.</p>
</div>
</div></div>    <div class="box item11"><div class="effect-7">
<div class="effect-img">
    <img height="240px" src="ontent/uploads/2014/11/PROD-Adolf-Hitler-whrend-einer-Rede.jpg" alt="Team Image">
</div>
<div class="effect-text">
    <h2>This is heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed purus consectetur, interdum felis in, auctor ligula.</p>
</div>
</div></div>








</div>
```

А нужно, чтобы получилась без верхнего длинного блока, как на рисунке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 300px); /*размер ячеек*/
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4,180px);/*высота ячеек*/
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: end;
}

.box {
  display:block;overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border:1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.item2 {
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">    
  <div class="box item2">
    <div class="effect-7">
    <div class="effect-img">
     <img height="240px" src="ijijimgdf/sad/bat.jpg" alt="Team Image">
    </div>
    <div class="effect-text">
      <h2>This is heading</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed purus consectetur, interdum felis in, auctor ligula.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  </div> 
    <div class="box item4"><div class="effect-7">
    <div class="effect-img">
      <img height="240px" src="ijijimgdf/menu/old.png" alt="Team Image">
    </div>
    <div class="effect-text">
      <h2>This is heading</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed purus consectetur, interdum felis in, auctor ligula.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box item5"> <div class="effect-7">
  <div class="effect-img">
    <img height="240px" src="ijijfiles/swfcas/fung.jpg" alt="Team Image">
  </div>
  <div class="effect-text">
    <h2>This is heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed purus consectetur, interdum felis in, auctor ligula.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
     <div class="box item6"><div class="effect-7">
<div class="effect-img">
    <img height="240px" src="ijijimgdf/story/med1.jpg" alt="Team Image">
</div>
<div class="effect-text">
    <h2>This is heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed purus consectetur, interdum felis in, auctor ligula.</p>
</div>
</div></div>
    <div class="box item7"><div class="effect-7">
<div class="effect-img">
    <img height="240px" src="ontent/uploads/2014/11/PROD-Adolf-Hitler-whrend-einer-Rede.jpg" alt="Team Image">
</div>
<div class="effect-text">
    <h2>This is heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed purus consectetur, interdum felis in, auctor ligula.</p>
</div>
</div></div>

    <div class="box item8"><div class="effect-7">
<div class="effect-img">
    <img height="240px" src="https://static.onecms.io/wp-content/uploads/sites/20/2020/09/11/nature.jpg" alt="Team Image">
</div>
<div class="effect-text">
    <h2>This is heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed purus consectetur, interdum felis in, auctor ligula.</p>
</div>
</div></div>    <div class="box item9"><div class="effect-7">
<div class="effect-img">
    <img height="240px" src="ontent/uploads/2014/11/PROD-Adolf-Hitler-whrend-einer-Rede.jpg" alt="Team Image">
</div>
<div class="effect-text">
    <h2>This is heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed purus consectetur, interdum felis in, auctor ligula.</p>
</div>
</div></div>


    <div class="box item10"><div class="effect-7">
<div class="effect-img">
    <img height="240px" src="ontent/uploads/2014/11/PROD-Adolf-Hitler-whrend-einer-Rede.jpg" alt="Team Image">
</div>
<div class="effect-text">
    <h2>This is heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed purus consectetur, interdum felis in, auctor ligula.</p>
</div>
</div></div>    <div class="box item11"><div class="effect-7">
<div class="effect-img">
    <img height="240px" src="ontent/uploads/2014/11/PROD-Adolf-Hitler-whrend-einer-Rede.jpg" alt="Team Image">
</div>
<div class="effect-text">
    <h2>This is heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed purus consectetur, interdum felis in, auctor ligula.</p>
</div>
</div></div>








</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо))) Честно говоря я никогда бы не додумался поставить span) пойду практиковаться сеткам дальше))